# What is the natural sequence of threads execution in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a telegram bot which has many commands which creates threads (thread with while True loop). How do I find out the execution sequence of these threads? suppose a command /start in telegram bot, creates and runs a thread with name t-start which is an infinite loop. Now I run another command /check in telegram bot which creates and runs a thread with name t-check which is also an infinite loop.

How do I find out the natural sequence of the execution of these threads?

Comment: The idea of threads is that they don't execute in sequence.

Comment: What Kaus said, but in different words: The entire point of threads is to allow [_concurrent computing_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing).

Comment: so by inserting some log or print statements  I can visually check the ongoing the thread execution. is that all I can do know the current thread executing?

Comment: @KawaiKx, If you have _no way_ of knowing whether some thread in your program is executing, then how is the thread doing anything useful? [P.S., Logging may be able to tell you about the "execution sequence" of your threads in a program that has logging enabled, but you can't rely on that sequence to be the same as if logging was not enabled. By changing what the threads do, you also change when the threads do it.]